# In Jmeter - Redirection not happening (Location in response headers not coming in reply response)

Tags: regex, redirect, jmeter, response-headers, extractor

Recorded Log-

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: FISServer
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; block-all-mixed-content
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 06:39:57 GMT
Location: https://temp1.temp2.com/pta/pages/index.jsp?st=J6UV-    D0EU-5TPE-7H5S-18ZA-TLAT-UVM7-5J4Z
```

Reply Log-

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: FISServer
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; block-all-mixed-content
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 07:23:35 GMT
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
```

1. Why am I not getting the Location header in reply log jmeter -> Tried Redirect Auto and Follow Redirects
2. I am not able to extract st value using RE extractor ->tried searching in response headers

Answer (score 0):

you most probably didn’t variabilize some id which can be in:

- header/cookie
- url parameter
- body of request

As a consequence you don’t get the successful response with 302, and instead get another response with code 200.

I suppose it’s a login screen you’re replaying.

Another possibility is missing Cookie Manager which ypu need to add with standard policy.

Comment: Its login request. I have checked my request formation of both recorded and reply and both looks similar except one correlated paramter name 'st'. Any other suggestion will be helpful